# What happens when we interchange the arrayname and index like index[arrayname] in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

What happens when we interchange the array name and index like index[arrayname] in C++? Is arrayname[index] the same as writing index[arrayname]? What will be the value in both?

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a C answer. The answer is more complicated in C++, no?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Nope.  This is something that is the same in both C and C++.

Comment: If the array is actually a `std::vector`, `std::array`, or some other array-like class with operator overloading, they can't be swapped. The trick doesn't translate so well to C++.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The op says they have an array, not a vector.  This only works with an array, so they must have been using an array.

Comment: It could be a `std::array`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It wouldn't compile if it was a `std::array`.

Comment: Dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a

Comment: _"...The built-in subscript expression E1[E2] is exactly identical to the expression *(E1 + E2)..."_ so `E1[E2] == *(E1 + E2) == *(E2 + E1) == E2[E1]` see __Built-in subscript operator___ here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

Comment: What I'm getting at is an answer for C++ should be along the lines of, "If you have a plain array then `array[index]` and `index[array]` are interchangeable. However, this trick doesn't work in general for other array-like types that overload `operator[]` like `std::array` or `std::vector`." And of course there should be a bunch of explanation.

Comment: We're always telling people that C and C++ are different languages. We shouldn't be closing this C++ question as a duplicate of a C question. The answers are different.

Comment: Despite being tagged C, the linked Q&A already has an answer explaining that this doesn't work with overloaded `[]`. :/

Answer (score 4):

For builtin types, the definition of `E1[E2]` "is identical (by definition) to" `*((E1) + (E2))`. (quotation from [expr.sub]/1) So the answer is simple: interchanging the names has no effect.

For user-defined types, `E1` has to be a class type with an overloaded `operator[]`, so, absent some funky stuff, you can't interchange the two expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It has no effect since `arrayname[index]` is identical writing as `index[arrayname]` cause both are interpreted as:
`*(arrayname + index)`